# Convert json-like string to dict in python

Tags: python, json

I have this data:

```py
"{
    'key': 'value',
    'key1': {
       [
            {
                'one': 'hi'
            },
            {
                'two': 'hi'
            }
        ]
    }
}"
```

I am trying to convert it to a dict so I can access its properties. I have tried `json.loads()`, `json.dumps()`, `eval()`, but none have been successful. What is the right way to convert this json-like string into a dict?

I have searched quite a bit on SO, but none of the answers are getting me past this. I'm fairly new to python.

I am getting this error when I replace the single quotes with double quotes and use `json.loads()`.

```py
E   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 133 (char 132)
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON, hence can not be converted directly into python objects (using primitives). You can try removing `{}` inside of value for `key1` (that's what causing the problem)

Comment: `json.loads` is the right way. The reason it didn't work is because, as Yevhen said, that's not valid JSON

Comment: I have tried replacing the single quotes with double quotes (which should be valid JSON), passed it through `json.loads()`, `json.dumps()`, and `eval()` with no luck. I will post the error I'm getting to the question when I use `json.loads()`.

Comment: Just replacing single quotes with double quotes won't make it a valid JSON. You have an invalid structure in `key1`

Comment: Thanks @YevhenKuzmovych. I guess I didn't realize I couldn't have an array of dicts in python.

Comment: No, you can have array of dicts. The problem is with `{[...]}` - this is not a valid JSON/python structure (is it set of lists? / dictionary without key?)

Comment: I see - I will more closely examine my data structure.

Comment: If you remove `{}` around your list, this will be valid and should work with either `json.loads()`(do use `json.loads()`) or `eval()` (don't use `eval`)